# Change fragment from another in app with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So, i have app with Navigation Drawer.
 I want to get put Extra in Fragment "ScreenSourceCollection" and get Extra in Fragment "ScreenPlayList". But if I call 
                i.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_BOOK_ID, bookId);
                startActivity(i);
I get fist screen with index 0 instead second screen with index 1. I realize that i make mistakes but i dont realise what i have to do.

my code below

```
ScreenSourceCollection

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_sources_albums, parent,false);
    ListView lvSourceList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvSourceList);

    database = new MediaDatabase(getActivity());
    mDB = new MediaDB(getActivity());
    mBooks = mDB.getBooks();

    BookAdapter bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(mBooks);
    lvSourceList.setAdapter(bookAdapter);

    lvSourceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1,
                                int position, long id) {

            Book book = (Book)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            long bookId = position;
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_BOOK_ID, bookId);
            startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(book.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

ScreenPlayList

```
public static ScreenPlayList newInstance (long bookId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(ARG_BOOK_ID, bookId);
    ScreenPlayList pl = new ScreenPlayList();
    pl.setArguments(args);
    return pl;

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] mScreenTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
public static final String EXTRA_BOOK_ID = "ru.thevoice.sounds.book_id";

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mScreenTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screen_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mScreenTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Initialize the first fragment when the application first loads.
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // Show toast about click.
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.action_search, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ScreenPlay();
            break;
        case 1:
            //fragment = new ScreenPlayList();
            long bookId = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_BOOK_ID, -1);
            if (bookId != -1) {
                fragment =  ScreenPlayList.newInstance(bookId);
            } else {
                fragment =  new ScreenPlayList();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ScreenSourcesCollection();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ScreenSettings();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ScreenPlayTabs();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mScreenTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // Error
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Error. Fragment is not created");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I do it, by keeping a reference to the fragment I want to pass a Bundle to:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(YourFragment.QUESTIONNUMBER, position + 1);
args.putSerializable(YourFragment.QUESTIONCONTENT, question);
currentFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Make String tags for every value you can pass inside of the fragment like

```
public static final String QUESTIONCONTENT = "question"
```

This way you always know exactly what to pass in order to prevent casting errors. Call your fragment, set the arguments bundle and in your fragment you can call:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int position = (Integer)args.get(QUESTIONNUMBER);
question = (Question)args.get(QUESTION);
```

This code is in my onCreateView, haven't really tried using it anywhere else. Good luck!

Comment: Great thanks, but i tell me, please:
1. How can i get currentFragment?
2. What i need to use in first fragment and what to use in second fragment?

Comment: Well, your fragments are always contained in an activity, so I assume you have code somewhere instantiating them meaning you can keep references somewhere. From there, you'd be able to create an interface which has methods that allow you to call specific methods for passing bundles or maybe require an args bundle in the constructor? Somehow you have to access the fragments from the activity enveloping them.